# How to add helper to simple_form depends of attribute type?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

This is my form:

```
= simple_form_for Risk.new do |f|
  = f.input :risk_id, as: :hidden, input_html: {value: risk.id}
  - if risk.answer_type.boolean?
    = f.input :answer, as: :radio_buttons
  - elsif risk.answer_type.string?
    = f.input :answer, as: :string
  - elsif risk.answer_type.integer?
    = f.input :answer, as: :integer
```

How to extract that if statement logic from view?

Answer (score 1):

You can setup a helper method in application_helper.rb. See below:

Your form.

```
= simple_form_fr Risk.new do |f|
   = f.input :risk_id, as: :hidden, input_html: {value: risk.id}
   = form_answer_type risk.answer_type, f
```

Your helper.

```
module ApplicationController

    def form_answer_type obj, f
      if obj.boolean?
        return f.input :answer, as: :radio_buttons
      elsif obj.string?
        return f.input :answer, as: :string
      elsif obj.integer?
        return f.input :answer, as: :integer
      end
    end

end
```

Take a look at ActionController::Helpers. They are quite powerful and can really help to keep you code clean and concise: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Helpers.html